# Enabling symlinks in Magento during setup process?

Tags: magento, vagrant

Is there a way to either enable symlinks during my Vagrant setup, or to directly modify my database to allow symlinks prior to a vagrant ssh?

The process I am trying to automate is this:

```
If using template files in a modman module, you must enable "Allow Symlinks" (found under System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer)
```

A better question might be, were is the `Allow Symlinks` value stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
# Turn on rewrites
# --------------------
curl -sSL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ehime/0dbe79875035d6235720/raw/9f91ed165b2e5a09797cd661c4a0f68b84581ff3/update-core-config.php -o shell/update-core-config.php
/usr/bin/php -f shell/update-core-config.php
/usr/bin/php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```